# SQLite slow select query - howto make it faster

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite

In SQLite I have a large DB (~35Mb).

It contains a table with the following syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE "log_temperature" (
"id"  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
"date"  datetime NOT NULL,
"temperature"  varchar(20) NOT NULL
)
```

Now when I want to search for datas within a period, it is too slow on an embedded system:

```
$ time sqlite3 sample.sqlite "select MIN(id) from log_temperature where 
date BETWEEN '2019-08-13 00:00:00' AND '2019-08-13 23:59:59';"
331106

real    0m2.123s
user    0m0.847s
sys     0m0.279s
```

Note1: ids are running from 210610 to 331600.

Note2: if I run 'SELECT id FROM log_temperature ORDER BY ASC LIMIT 1', it gives the exact same timing as with the 'MIN' function.

I want to have the 'real time of 0m2.123s' to be as close to 0m0.0s as possible.

What are my options for making this faster? (Without removing hundreds of thousands of data?)

ps.: embedded system parameters are not important here. This shall be solved by optimizing the query or the underlying schema.

Comment: Is there any indexes?

Comment: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-index/

Comment: @Sami: yes, id has an index, and also (id,date) has it. Now I did not know that index can also be defined without being unique so I added an index now for the date field and this eliminated the slow queries - as Patrick suggested firstly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you create an index on the date?

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON log_temperature(date);
```

Answer (score 5):

First, I would recommend that you write the query as:

```
select MIN(id)
from log_temperature 
where date >= '2019-08-13' and date < '2019-08-14';
```

This doesn't impact performance, but it makes the query easier to write -- and no need to fiddle with times.

Then, you want an index on `(date, id)`:

```
create index idx_log_temperature_date_id on log_temperature(date, id);
```

I don't think `id` is needed in the index, if it is declared as the primary key of the table.